# Laravel API Routing Not Doing Throttling - Always Set To Default 60,1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6, laravel-spark

I have a group of endpoints that I want to have a throttle of 10 requests per minute. Currently, my endpoint group looks like this:

```
Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'auth:api', 'throttle:10,1'
], function () {
// endpoints here
}
```

The issue is that when I view my headers, the rate limit is set at the standard 60 per minute. What am I doing wrong? Or do you know a different way?

The response data is as follows:

```
cache-control: no-cache, private
content-encoding: gzip
content-type: application/json
date: Tue, 01 May 2018 20:08:55 GMT
server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
status: 200
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-ratelimit-limit: 60
x-ratelimit-remaining: 59
```

I tried the following:

```
Route::group([
    'middleware' => ['auth:api', 'throttle:10,1']
], function () {
// rest of code
```

But got the same result. So then I tried:

```
Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'throttle:10,1', 'auth:api'
], function () {
// rest of code
```

However, this gave me a 500 error. This told me that the middleware definitely had to be an array. However, when it is an array, it doesn't set the throttle to what I want it to be.

Comment: What do the headers say?

Comment: cache-control: no-cache, private
content-encoding: gzip
content-type: application/json
date: Tue, 01 May 2018 20:08:55 GMT
server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
status: 200
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-ratelimit-limit: 60
x-ratelimit-remaining: 59

Comment: Since that's a lot of text that'd benefit from better formatting, edit your question to include that. In a comment it's just a jumble.

Comment: Done! :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no way to test this, but I suspect you want:

```
Route::group([
    'middleware' => ['auth:api', 'throttle:10,1']
], function () {
// rest of code
```

([docs source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware#middleware-groups))

That is, without putting `'auth:api'` and `'throttle:10,1'` into one array Laravel has no way to understand that the latter is also middleware.

Comment: I have updated my question in response to this. Thank you for the heads up. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I went into my Kernel.php file and added a new middleware group with the throttle I was wanting and removed the standard api one. This worked. I will have to create a new middleware group for each new one I make as well. I do not think it was supposed to be like this, but it is for now. Thank you for your help guys!